# Can't seem to kill a process with bash script

Tags: linux, bash, raspberry-pi

I've been trying to kill a process with a batch script and I can't seem to get it working I've read a lot of tutorials online and tried different things and I can't seem to get it to kill the process

how it's run: (crontab)

```
* * * * * /home/pi/status.sh > /home/pi/logs/status.log 2>&1
```

log:

```
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
  Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
^M  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0^M100    10  100    10    0     0     73      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   153^M100    10  100    10    0     0     72      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   $
/home/pi/status.sh: 6: /home/pi/status.sh: 18645: not found
```

status.sh:

```
Bridge=$(curl http://www.mywebsite.com/dir/cache/timestamp.txt)
timestamp=$( date +%s )

total=`expr $timestamp - $Bridge`

if (($total > 300));
then
#p=$(pidof cgminerEU)
#sudo killall -9 cgminerEU
#sudo kill -9 $(pidof cgminerEU)
sudo pkill -f cgminerEU
fi
```

the process in question

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ ps ax | grep cgminerEU
26018 ?        Ss     0:13 SCREEN -dm ./cgminerEU
26019 pts/0    Ssl+  89:32 ./cgminerEU
30989 pts/2    S+     0:00 grep --color=auto cgminerEU
```

does the
    /home/pi/status.sh: 6: /home/pi/status.sh: 18645: not found
mean that it's trying to kill pid 18645? I'm sorry I'm new to bash scripting and it's all very confusing

Comment: *18645: not found mean that it's trying to kill pid 18645?* - exactly. you can debug what's happening by running `ps ax` before you run kill $PID in order to see if the $PID has been detected correctly.

also, `set -x` at the beginning of the script would be helpful.

Comment: well.. I did the debug thing and everything is as it should be except for it trying to kill a nonexistent process I tried running the file directly through ssh ./status.sh and it ran and killed it so something with it being a cronjob must be messing it up :\

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect you'll find that this is due to a race condition.

1. If you kill `screen`, `cgminerEU` will immediately die and vice versa
2. You've made `pkill` send a signal to both processes

`pkill` is in a race to kill the second process before it dies.

I suggest you try removing the `-f` from `pkill` to make it kill only by process name and not full command line.

This way, it will kill only the `cgminerEU` process and not the `screen` process of the same name (which will die as a dependency anyways).

PS: `curl` has a `-s` to avoid getting emailing the progress indicator.